# Mesosphere DCOS Dashboard metrics graphs does not move

Tags: graph, dashboard, metrics, mesosphere, dcos

I installed a new DCOS Cluster, Version 1.11.3, which includes 3 masters and 3 slaves, i can see them all from the DCOS Dashboard. My problem is that the graphs of the system resources (CPU Allocation, Memory Allocation, Disk Allocation) does not move at all, i see them empty, Components Tab show all as Healthy and the Nodes show the connected Nodes right.

What might be the problem ? i did not install any of the services yet (Cassandra , Kafka or Spark), but it should show the Metrics at least !

Need to add:
I don't have any failed services, also the metrics service is up on all nodes:

```
[id@cluster ~]$ sudo systemctl | grep dcos | grep metric
  dcos-metrics-master.service     loaded active running   DC/OS Metrics Master: exposes node metrics
  dcos-metrics-master.socket      loaded active running   DC/OS Metrics Master Socket: socket for DC/OS Metrics Master service
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved, as it was supposed to install Services, if Services are not installed, then no graphs will be shown.